How do I import CA certificates from Hashicorp into Azure API Management using terraform?
I have uploaded CA certificates manually to Azure APIM Service but I want to achieve this through terraform.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have gone through the documentation here - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_certificate but not so helpful.
If someone has done this before or have links or resources that show how this can be achieved with terraform, that will be great. Thank you.
I have uploaded the CA certificate files on Azure portal and they work well with python client script. There are successful APIM authentications to Open AI instance from the client app.
I now need to upload the CA certificates files with terraform code. Can some one help?

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look here first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
